# Gitlab-CI and Artifactory without Maven?

Tags: gitlab-ci, artifactory

I would like to build a rpm package from a python module and save it in the Artifactory. Do I have to use Maven or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the packages the way you are used to, and deploy them to Artifactory via [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) / [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) / [Artifactory JAVA client](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java) / [Go client](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go).

The best way will be using the JFrog CLI to collect and publish Build Info.
You can read [here](https://jfrog.com/blog/gitlab-and-artifactory-on-your-mark-get-set-build/) about integrating with GitLab CI. Although this blog is a bit out-dated, you can see some examples and understand the advantages of collecting the Build Info.